# DSaaS Adding Global Rule with Python

Tags: python, deepsecurity

Trying to use the automation API example to add a global rule to DSaaS.  I have no idea how to populate the hash,description pairs in the globalrules = deepsecurity.ApplicationControlGlobalRules().

Tried using JSON but don't know how to do that.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, warnings
import deepsecurity
from deepsecurity.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

# Setup
if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
configuration = deepsecurity.Configuration()
configuration.host = 'YOUR_HOST'

# Authentication
configuration.api_key['api-secret-key'] = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

# Initialization
# Set Any Required Values
api_instance = deepsecurity.GlobalRulesApi(deepsecurity.ApiClient(configuration))
globalrules = deepsecurity.ApplicationControlGlobalRules()
api_version = 'YOUR VERSION'

try:
    api_response = api_instance.add_global_rules(globalrules, api_version)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("An exception occurred when calling GlobalRulesApi.add_global_rules: %s\n" % e)
```

I'd like to know how to populate the hash,description pair in the object that is passed to the add_global_rules method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you would like to add some Global Application Control Rules to your DSaaS account using the Python SDK. In order to do this, first create the rules like so

```py
rules = []
rules.append(deepsecurity.ApplicationControlGlobalRule(sha256="YOUR_SHA256_HERE", description="YOUR_DESCRIPTION_HERE"))
...
```

appending more rules as required. Then add them to the `ApplicationControlGlobalRules` object

```py
globalrules = deepsecurity.ApplicationControlGlobalRules(application_control_global_rules = rules)
```

In general your code sample will be as follows

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, warnings
import deepsecurity
from deepsecurity.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

# Setup
if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
configuration = deepsecurity.Configuration()
configuration.host = 'YOUR_HOST'

# Authentication
configuration.api_key['api-secret-key'] = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

# Initialization
# Set Any Required Values
api_instance = deepsecurity.GlobalRulesApi(deepsecurity.ApiClient(configuration))
api_version = 'YOUR VERSION'

# Create empty list for Global Application Control Rules
rules = []
rules.append(deepsecurity.ApplicationControlGlobalRule(sha256="YOUR_SHA256_HERE", description="YOUR_DESCRIPTION_HERE"))
# ... Add more Global Application Control Rules as required here

# Create ApplicationControlGlobalRules object with the rules
globalrules = deepsecurity.ApplicationControlGlobalRules(application_control_global_rules = rules)

try:
    api_response = api_instance.add_global_rules(globalrules, api_version)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("An exception occurred when calling GlobalRulesApi.add_global_rules: %s\n" % e)
```

P.S. I work for Trend Micro on the Deep Security team.

Comment: Beautiful!  Works like a charm!  Thank you much!